# Keep cursor on when sculpting

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

I'm new on sculpting so I have what I think is a basic question but I can't find an answer.
When I sculpt the round cursor disappear, there is a way to keep always on?
I found the option to disable the cursor, but I want the exact opposite if possible.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: hello, what round cursor are you talking about? you can enable the Move / Rotate / Scale gizmos while in Sculpt mode if you want (Viewport Gizmos panel on the top right of the 3D view)

Comment: I mean the sculpt brush, the blue circle. It disappear when I sculpt. https://i.imgur.com/FoXcHPs.jpg

Comment: oh ok you're right